# Design patterns: Continue

Tags: python, design-patterns, refactoring

If you define a pattern as a clever trick that helps you solve a programming problem in an elegant and perhaps more readable way[[1]](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Er5K_nR5lDQ&feature=plcp). What are the design patterns for using the `continue` statement (if one is avoiding deeply nested `if` statements)?

```
for item in items:
    if is_for_sale(item):
        cost=compute_cost(item)
        if cost<=wallet.money:
            buy(item)

for item in items:
    if not is_for_sale(item):
        continue
    cost = compute_cost(item)
    if cost > wallet.money:
        continue
    buy(item)
```

Comment: A design pattern is not an implementation pattern. So not sure what you are asking.

Comment: `continue` is a very common feature in other languages -- I think it's called `continue` in `C` as well, and `cycle` in fortran.  I don't really use it much in python (as I haven't found as great of a need)

Comment: @ mgilson -- that was the reason i asked this question, it seems that there aren't many cases where it is actually used (or maybe even where it should be used)...

Answer (score 5):

This is not design pattern. But when you have many nested loops, and it's not clear what happening there, then it is a code smell. What I would recommend to do here is two refactorings - [Extract Method](http://martinfowler.com/refactoring/catalog/extractMethod.html) and [Replace Nested Conditional With Guard](http://martinfowler.com/refactoring/catalog/replaceNestedConditionalWithGuardClauses.html).

First, extract items processing to show what you are doing:

```
for(item in items)
   try_to_buy(item)
```

Then apply guards in new method:

```
def try_to_buy(item):
   if not is_for_sale(item):
       return

   if compute_cost(item) > wallet.money:
       return

   buy(item)
```

Comment: I've converted your code to python. Feel free to rollback if you disagree.

Comment: I don't know what, if any, refactoring method it is, but I'd change the function body into a single `if is_for_sale(item) and compute_cost(item) <= wallet.money: buy(item)` in any language that short-circuited logical expressions. No `continue` statements required.

Comment: @martineau those statements are `return` statements. The less conditional logic your code have, the easier it is to understand

Comment: I consider multiple `return` statements a code smell and often find them more difficult to understand that an `if` statement with a single `and` in it.

Comment: @martineau then you are smarter, than me and Martin Fowler :) you are lucky guy! Actually this goes to psychology. Avery `and` adds one more thing to keep in mind.

Comment: @martineau: The earlier you can exit a method the less code the developer has to read.

Comment: @jgauffin: Using my suggestion, the developer only has to read a single `if` statement at the beginning of the function (assuming her mind is capable of understanding the "complex" logical expression proposed).

Comment: @martineau: I missed the `with a single and in it` part of your comment.

Answer (score 2):

This is slightly off topic, but if you are looking for way to simplify your code you could do:

```
items_for_sale = (item for item in items if is_for_sale(item))
for item in items_for_sale:
    if compute_cost(item) <= wallet.money:
        buy(item)
```

As far as your original question goes, I would only use a `continue` if it prevents having to indent more than one line. If you only have a single line in your if statement then It doesn't make much sense to `continue`.

Comment: You're missing a close paren in your `items_for_sale` generator.

Comment: @ Nathan Villaescusa -- if am not sure if it simplifies the code(at least readability), for me the use of the contiunue in the example made the code much more readable...

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you say `continue` is not heavily used, because I at-least use it to continue when conditions are not met, instead of checking for all conditions, that way code is flat and `Flat is better than nested.`

sometime I use exceptions to indicate state-change and come out of deeply nested inner loops or functions e.g.

```
class MyException(Exception): pass

for item in items:
   try:
       for user in item.users:
           check_user(user)
   except MyException:
       continue

def check_user(user):
    if user.bad:
        raise MyException("bad user")
```

Comment: @ Anurag Uniyal -- +1, this is exactly what i was looking for.